# Function that only ever returns null in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to declare a function that only ever returns `null`? Unfortunately, you cannot write `null` in the return type section. The return value should be `null` and not Unit so that it can work with nullable operators.

Comment: How about the type `Nothing?` which can only be `null`?

Comment: What do you mean? `fun f() = null` does not work?

Comment: @Naetmul: It has to do something then return null. I think Michael has the solution here.

Comment: What's the point of returning something, if what is returned is always null? Why not return Unit (i.e. void)?

Comment: @JBNizet: Good question. Because an implementation of the same interface isn't always null

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As also suggested in the comments, `Nothing?` should be the return type of such a function:

```
fun alwaysNull(): Nothing? = null
```

The [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html#the-nothing-type) states:

> [...] Another case where you may encounter this type is type inference. The nullable variant of this type, `Nothing?`, has exactly one possible value, which is `null`. If you use `null` to initialize a value of an inferred type and there's no other information that can be used to determine a more specific type, the compiler will infer the `Nothing?` type:
>
> ```
> val x = null           // 'x' has type `Nothing?`
> val l = listOf(null)   // 'l' has type `List<Nothing?>
> ```

Comment: In contrast KDoc of [Nothing](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/v1.8.0/core/builtins/native/kotlin/Nothing.kt) states: "for example, if a function has the return type of Nothing, it means that it never returns (always throws an exception)" but it just returns `null` in your case thus the usage of `Nothing` is arguable. Also what should a **nullable** Nothing mean?